# display report mvc rdlc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

Im building my first MVC in Visual Studio 2017. Have just designed an RDLC report and now id like to create a button on one of my views that opens the report in a new window as a pdf

and hopefully another button that lets them download that pdf without opening (but this isnt 100% necessary)

Have literally no idea how to code that button
Have been googling and searching with no luck. Can anyone here help?

Comment: What kind of button? A simple HTML button? A complete menu? I think you will need to research a little bit... look for a framework which offers you the features you desire (e.g. Kendo UI from Telerik or maybe jQuery UI)?

Opening a file as download instead of in-browser can be found by searching stackoverflow.

Comment: literally just a simple html button. Does it matter? ill honestly use any type of button to get this done. Just need to know what to put in the onclick event in order to display the report as a pdf

Comment: Your question sounds like you're looking for a dropdown-menu. I've posted an answer how to realize the download with a simple button. Of course you can use the onclick-function everywhere else ;)

Answer (score 0):

With the given information this is pretty simple:

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Download" onclick="startDownload();" />
```

JavaScript

```
function startDownload() {
   var url = '@(Url.Action("GetRDLC", "Report"))';
   window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

ReportController.cs

```
public FileResult GetRDLC() {
   var fname = "MyFileName.pdf";
   var pdf = new byte[] { };

   /* FILL pdf-array HERE */

   // Add header to tell browser this is a download
   Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + fname);
   return File(pdf, "application/pdf", "");
}
```

All you need to add is the signature to GetRDLC if you need parameters for the report.